# Использование кода из github законно ли

Tags: git, github, лицензирование, контроль-версий

Будет ли какая-то ответственность за использование кода без ссылки на авторов лицензию и прочее

Comment: Та там же пишут как правило лицензионное соглашение авторы.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы будете использовать в своем маленьком проекте, который никто не увидит, то скорее всего ничего не будет (ну может совесть помучает).

Другое дело, если на базе этого получится мало-мальски продаваемый и/или популярный продукт и юристы узнают о использовании кода. А тут может быть все что угодно - от просто предложения договорится до больших штрафов и судов. Достаточно посмотреть на схватки больших гигантов и все станет ясно.

Но опять же, ответственность сильно зависит от стран проживания.

Comment: Уголовная ответственность возможна

Comment: это вопрос или утверждение?

Comment: Ето Вопрос 
81.5k●4●59●116
Уголовная ответственность возможна –

Comment: Надо смотреть, под какой лицензией выложен код. Вот перевод большинства лицензий, можно посмотреть какие правила использования кода http://licenseit.ru/

Comment: @user221117 все зависит от объемов и страны. Вполне возможно, что в какой то стране просто пальчиком пожурят, а в какой то и расстрел дадут.

Comment: Все прямо так серьезно

Comment: На самом деле нет. Скорее всего либо просто ничего не будет, либо просто обратятся юристы и предложат решить этот вопрос. И возможно, и предложение будет нормальным.
но может просто не повезет и попасть на показательный суд  как "злостный нарушитель" (при этом якобы просто строку случайно скопировав) и отхватить по максимуму. А если бы это был Советский Союз образца 35-37, то лагеря самое оно.

Comment: Ну а например если использовать целый проект полностью без изменений только название изменить и например где то его подать на грант или иной конкурс без ведома авторов то что тогда будет?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, Вы хотите нарушить закон и что бы Вас уверили, что это нормально? В Вашем случае скорее всего будет ок, но как только те, кто грант давали поймут подлог, может все пойти наперекосяк. В лучшем случае просто попросят вернуть деньги назад

Comment: Нет просто ентересно что будет

Comment: @KoVadim Советский Союз и GitHub? У вас прям киберпанк тут.

Comment: @user221117 это мошенничество, ничего хорошего не будет.

Comment: А вот если интерфейс будет почти полностью взят, а вот код будет разный, то что тогда будет?  так можно делать?

Comment: почему Вы пытаетесь найти обходной путь? Но как показывает практика гугл против оракл и майкрософт против реактос и ряд ещё, в этом случае очень спорно и судится можно долго и нудно.

Comment: Я так не понял что за это будет?

Comment: Да вот мировое сообщество также не может понять. Часть людей утверждает, что интерфейсы не есть чем то таким, что нельзя скопировать и переписать реализацию (юристы гугла), а кто то (оракл), что каждая буковка в их коде защищена.
Но если Вам очень сильно хочется узнать, что Вам за это будет - берите любой популярный продукт и копипасте. Потом отпишитесь. Хотя может Вам повезет и о Вас напишут в новостях как о [Попове и его новой ОС](http://www.bolgenos.su/) с нескучными обоями.